# scala call shell command "rm -rf *" does not work

Tags: scala, shell

I have following code to call shell command in scala, create a directory

```
import scala.sys.process._
"mkdir /tmp/mydir1".!
"mkdir /tmp/mydir2".!
```

the directory is created, now I am removing all of them by

```
"rm -rf /tmp/mydir*".!
```

nothing is removed

How to do it correctly?

Comment: Have you the rights to remove the directories ?

Comment: Generally, the creator of a directory has the rights to remove their own directories.

Comment: I would try a "ls -l /tmp/mydir*".! to see if that gives you any hints, and a "ls -l /tmp" too.

Comment: Does `!` use a shell to execute the command? A shell is required to expand the glob pattern. Perhaps you need. `"sh -c 'rm -r /tmp/mydir*'".!` Or perhaps `"find /tmp -maxdepth 1 -name 'mydir*' -type d -delete".!`

Comment: Why use Scala to call shell programs?  The language is fully capable of doing both of these operations without the overhead of extra processes.

Comment: @EdwinBuckE this is just part of my program, actually I use tar file and want to delete many of them after extracted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(For those less familar with Scala)

In your code, you have
`import scala.sys.process._`
which includes
`scala.sys.process.ProcessImplicits`
The implicit conversion being applied transforms the `String` to a `ProcessBuilder` with 
`implicit def stringToProcess(command: String): ProcessBuilder`
That abstract `ProcessBuilder` class has an function named 
`def !():Int` 
which launches the process, returning the exit code as an `Int`.

Thus `"rm -rf /tmp/mydir1".!` is roughly 
`new ProcessBuilder("rm -rf /tmp/mydir1").!()`

The main issue is that `rm` doesn't do wild card expansion.  It's actually handled by the shell (typically a Bash Shell) through Glob expansion before the `rm` command even reads its parameters.  This means that you cannot "just" call `rm` the way you want to; because, `rm` will then error out with some sort of "file not found" error (as a file with a `*` in it doesn't exist).

So, what you need to do is to launch a `bash` process, with arguments to run the `rm` command

```
Seq("bash", "-c", "rm -rf /tmp/mydir*").!
```

Which will use
`implicit def stringSeqToProcess( command: collection.Seq[String] ): ProcessBuilder`

Note that the command now is passed as an argument to `-c` and the command you are running is really Bash.

Another option is to simply filter the contents of a directory, and remove those.

```
new File("/tmp").listFiles()
  .filter(_.isDirectory && _.name.startsWith("mydir"))
  .map(_.delete())
```

should probably do the trick.

And creating the directory would probably work with

```
new File("/tmp/mydir1").mkdirs()
```

Comment: Scala `sys.process._` won't parse a quote-delimited sub-string as expected. It ignores the quote marks and splits everything at the whitespace.

Comment: @jwvh Thanks I'll break it into a `Seq` then.  Really, I'm not a fan of this implicit, but I like explicit stuff, so I'm biased. :)

Answer (score 3):

The expansion of `*` into existing file names is done by the shell. Scala `sys.process` methods do not invoke the shell for command-line processing.

To make that work you need to invoke the shell directly:

```
Seq("sh", "-c", "rm -rf /tmp/mydir*").!
```